# splitting string within brackets

Tags: jquery

I have `var string = (2200 x 1500)(2441 x 1610)`

I want to split the string into arrays from within the brackets so `href[0] = (2200 x 1500)` and `href[1] = (2441 x 1610)`

I have tried this:

```
var href = [];
  $(document).each(function () {
      var hey = matchingDivs.text();
      var res = hey.split(")(");
      href.push(res);
  });
```

so that when I alert like this `alert("("+href[href.length -1]);` the result should be `(2441 x 1610)` but instead it is coming up with [see JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3d7wV/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
var href = $.trim($("#matchingDivs").text()).match(/\(.*?\)/g);  
console.log(href);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ajqy5/)

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
  var hey = $("#matchingDivs").text();
  var href = hey.match(/\(([^()]+)\)/g);

  alert(href[0]);
  alert(href[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var string = "(2200 x 1500)(2441 x 1610)";

var href = string.replace(")(", ")#(").split("#");
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're misunderstanding what `push` does (see [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)).

It just appends whatever is passed in as new element to the array.

So in your case, it appends the whole result from split (an array) to the end of your `href` array. So in the end you have 2-deep array, the outer one with size 1, the inner one with size 2 holding the elements you are looking for.

You are however expecting it to add the elements returned by split into your array.

Furthermore, you could have tried to first simplify your example (by leaving out the parsing text from a div, which has nothing to do with the actual problem).